# valueof method in class Integer

Tags: java

We know that valueof method in Integer class is static. But when we call by an object of Integer class then it is not giving any error. ex: following code is running perfectly...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Integer i=new Integer(5);
        System.out.println(i.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: static methods can be invoked like class methods

Comment: This is valid because uhh... the designers of Java said so. Not sure what answer to give beyond copy-pasting from the JLS.

Comment: because static method can only be accessed by class , not by object

Comment: This code works perfectly fine, and in accordance with how the documentation describes it should work.

Comment: Can you give me that link where you saw that

Comment: @ParthPatel what makes you think that?  It's a terrible idea to access static methods with objects, but it's still allowed.

Comment: @ParthPatel While it is true that `static method can only be accessed by class , not by object`, the language simply allows you to write it as if you were invoking it on an instance. (Which is a huge mistake in my opinion, but it is what it is.) Your code is just shorthand for `System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(i));`.

Comment: While Java syntax allows non-static access to static members, the Eclipse Java compiler at least thinks that this is a bad idea, and allows you to configure if this should be treated as warning or error.

Comment: @wero That's the first thing I do when installing Eclipse afresh, the second is to treat assignments that have no effect as errors too.

Comment: @biziclop I change every "ignore" to "warning", except "Non-externalized strings", "Boxing and unboxing conversions", and sometimes "Method can potentially be static". Code should be warning-free before check-in.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting the Java tutorial on ["Understanding Class Members"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> **Note:** You can also refer to static methods with an object reference like
>       `instanceName.methodName(args)`
>   but this is discouraged because it does not make it clear that they are class methods.

This should be as good an official source as any.

---

The JLS stuff that seems to apply:

> #### [15.12.3. Compile-Time Step 3: Is the Chosen Method Appropriate?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3)
>
> ⋯
>
> - The invocation mode, computed as follows:
> - - If the compile-time declaration has the `static` modifier, then the invocation mode is `static`.
>
> #### [15.12.4.1. Compute Target Reference (If Necessary)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1)
>
> ⋯
>
> - If form is *ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier*, then:
> - - If the invocation mode is `static`, then there is no target reference. The *ExpressionName* is evaluated, but the result is then discarded.
> - - ⋯
> - If the form is *Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier* involved, then:
> - - If the invocation mode is `static`, then there is no target reference. The *Primary* expression is evaluated, but the result is then discarded.
> - - ⋯

So, it's allowed insofar as there are rules defined for how to evaluate that sort of expression. Which is that:

- `static` methods are *always* called using a `static` invocation. (This seems obvious, but it's still something that should be specified. Say, hypothetically, Java introduces something like C# extension methods in the future, those would follow different rules.)
- The value of the receiver expression is *ignored* for the purposes of the static method call. (Although it does get evaluated before the call.)

This is how such a call is evaluated at runtime. That's a a distinct step from how the compiler determines the method to call, which happens earlier. However, that part of the spec is inscrutable to me. That said it's easy to verify that the compile-time type of the receiver expression matters there, as does the fact that the method being called is `static`. (The static type is all the compiler has to work with, and static calls are early-bound.)

Comment: I'm looking for the relevant bits in the JLS, but I have a hunch that this rule isn't spelled out there.

Comment: It is in [JLS 15.12.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3): *If the compile-time declaration has the `static` modifier, then the invocation mode is `static`.* Meaning that if a static method is called in a non-static mode (read: on instance value), then it is still treated as a static call.

Comment: Also in [JLS 15.12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1): *If the invocation mode is `static`, then there is no target reference. The expression Primary is evaluated, but the result is then discarded.* So, if the expression before the method name is evaluated, and any exception or side effect is still applicable, but a null value will not cause NPE, since the result is not actually used.

Comment: You should edit answer to include these references, if you want.

Comment: It is also in [JLS 6.5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.2) .

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I think 15.12.4.1 is the most relevant one here where the question is "why is this allowed."

Comment: Actually, doesn't explain "why". The answer to that is that it's probably because it was allowed in C++. *<shrugs>*

Comment: Okay, so to "why it works," which is the best we can do without interrogating Gosling.

Answer (score 0):

what's more interesting is this case:

```
public class A {
  public static int foo() {
    return 0;
  }
}

public class B extends A{
  public static int foo() {
    return 1;
  }
}

public static void bar() {
  A a = new B();
  System.out.println("val: " + a.foo());
}
```

Prints '0', because `a` is declared as an `A`

Comment: It get worse, if you say `A a = null;`, the code still works and prints `0`.

Comment: @biziclop Why "worse"? The `null` reference isn't being dereferenced or otherwise used at runtime, there's no reason to throw a NPE. (As opposed to during an instance method call, when the runtime type has to be determined for purposes of late binding.)

Comment: @biziclop Worse in the sense that it's even more confusing. The language developers really dropped the ball when they thought this was a good idea.

Comment: @biziclop How so? What should they have done? Added a runtime check on every static call with a receiver to emit a NPE, even though the runtime value to be checked is otherwise unnecessary? I mean I understand why it seems "odd", but I don't think you can propose an improvement that would do anything besides complicate the evaluation rules of the language for no benefit.

Comment: @biziclop The reason a NPE is emitted usually is that it's literally impossible to correctly call an instance method with a null receiver, since in a mainstream OOP language, the runtime type of the receiver determines which method to call for a given selector. (C++ is the anomaly here because it allows for early-bound instance method calls.) But a static method call *has no receiver*, so why bother with it at all? At no point are you actually dereferencing the expression before the dot operator.

Comment: @millimoose Look, I understand all of that full well. But don't you think it is a bad idea that to figure out whether an operator is invoked or not, you have to check the source of another class? Imagine if it was say the `+` operator. How bad would it be? (And yes, I know that in C++ that's how things actually work, but that's the norm there, whereas in Java they omitted operator overloading to avoid this kind of puzzle. And then they did this.)

Comment: @biziclop I don't think this specific case warrants adding a runtime check to every static invocation that would throws an exception for code that would work, and work exactly the same, if you had written the class name before the dot instead of an expression. You're marginally slowing things down, you're not preventing any actual bugs, all you'd achieve is a foolish consistency in the name of meaningless pedanticism. I suppose it depends on whether your mental model is that the dot is an operator that's being invoked, except that's not the case.

Comment: @millimoose Who said anything about a runtime check? A runtime check would be clearly a bad idea for the reasons you outlined. It's just a confusing construct and should be banned altogether. And then the dereferencing operator would always dereference, making code far easier to read. And you wouldn't see anyone writing `int i = new Integer(str).parseInt(str);` like I saw once. :)